# Trying to run Quartz scheduler with HSQL database, getting errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, hsqldb

I have set up HSQL Db according to this article: [hsql installation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hsqldb/hsqldb_installation.htm)

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzDataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_hsqldb.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_hsqldb.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at com.example.blockchaininfo.BlockChainInfoApplication.main(BlockChainInfoApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_hsqldb.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_hsqldb.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:453) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:240) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceInitializer.initialize(AbstractDataSourceInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_hsqldb.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getReader(EncodedResource.java:146) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.readScript(ScriptUtils.java:282) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:450) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
... 28 common frames omitted
```

I have also tried setting up different properties via `application.properties` like:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
jdbc.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/testDB
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

Any idea what's going on? I feel like I missed some settings.

**EDIT**

Pom file as requested. Removed the irrelevant dependencies. I've tried searching for that file, but it's just non-existent. Not sure, whether I should be the one adding it or should some setting be set. If it's on my side, where to put it?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <!--Version is not needed when used with Spring Boot parent pom file -->
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shared-utils</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: _I feel like I missed some settings._ Yes, the error message `class path resource [org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_hsqldb.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist` sounds like that exact thing. Ehere does your `tables_hsqldb.sql` lay?

Comment: The error message is very specific - what don't you understand about it

Comment: It clearly states the issue. Check whether the specified file exists at the said location

Comment: Can i see your pom file,if you are using RAMJobStore, ideally you don't need define spring datasource connection, if you are using you need to provide spring default path for your tables_hsqldb.sql... Check out this class from spring boot ..https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/quartz/QuartzProperties.java

Comment: I feel dumb now. How do I check that location? As for Spring I would normally put the `.sql` file under /resources folder.

Comment: I've figured out there's no chance to find the location since it's a dependency stuff. So the file is built after the project is built. It''s more like a configurational problem.